# Restlet client on Android: can't get off the ground :(

Tags: java, android, rest, restlet

I've been playing around a bit with restlet, and so far I like it :)

I am having some trouble getting a restlet client to work on an android emulator, though.

Right now a have a very simple restlet server running under JSE.  All it does is expose a root resource (which for the moment is just a line of text) via the GET method.  I can get consume the resource with a browser, and also with a simple restlet client running in the console.  I have modified the code for the JSE client to try to connect from an android emulator but I can't get it to work:

```
package mypackage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.TextView;

import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

  super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    ClientResource res = new ClientResource( "http://server-ip:8111/" );
    Representation rep = res.get();

    TextView tv = new TextView( this );
    try {
      tv.setText( rep.getText() );
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
      tv.setText( "Exception: " + ex.getMessage() );
    }
    setContentView( tv );

  }

}
```

Notes:

(1) The built-in browser on the android emulator can connect to the web service and retrieve the text.

(2) The project Manifest.xml file has been modified to enable the uses-permission INTERNET.

(3) The following client using the Apache HttpClient library that comes bundled with android works just fine:

```
package mypackage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet( "http://server-ip:8111/" );
        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        TextView tv = new TextView( this );

        try {
            String content = client.execute( get, handler );
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            setContentView( tv );
            tv.setText( content );
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            tv.setText( "Exception: " + ex.getMessage() );
        }

    }

}
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Mike.

Comment: How does "not work" manifest itself? Does it throw an exception? Return something, but not what you expect? ...

Comment: Sorry, I thought I put that in the original post.  The HTTP request times out, I believe.  There is a long delay, and then a message box on the android emulator pops up telling me the app has unexpectedly quit.  I'm going to try to use a web debugger (Charles) to examine what the request looks like, but I need to figure out how to set the proxy in Eclipse first >:|

Comment: Have you solved the issue? One workaround is to register the org.restlet.ext.httpclient extension manually to replace the internal/default HTTP client. See Restlet user guide:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to register the org.restlet.ext.httpclient extension manually to replace the internal/default HTTP client. See Restlet user guide:
http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/275-restlet/266-restlet.html

Recent Restlet 2.1 snapshots have also fixed a long standing issue with the internal HTTP connector that could cause unexpected timeouts.